# Group of order 35 operating on a set of order 5

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

I am trying to prove the following:

*If G is a group of order 35 and operates nontrivially on a set of five elements, then there exists a normal subgroup of order 7.*

I saw that it is possible to solve this problem using Sylow's theory, for example [Group of order 35, and normal subgroup of order 7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581406/group-of-order-35-and-normal-subgroup-of-order-7). But with the hypothesis of my problem is it necessary to use this theory? How would this be done?

Comment: Is your condition correctly stated? Every group operates on a set of order 5, e.g. via the trivial action, so your hypothesis doesn't add much information.

Comment: I'm sorry, I already corrected that part. G operates nontrivially on that set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

group actions are simply homomorphisms into a symmetric group ( https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/11/06/group-actions-i/ ). In the case of this problem, we have $\phi:G\to S_5$ where $|G|=35$. However, any homomorphic images of $G$ necessarily have orders 35, 5, 7, or 1 (by the first isomorphism theorem and logic on factor groups). If it isn't 1 (that would be the trivial action), and 35 and 7 are out of the question (as homomorphic images are subgroups, and $7\not\mid5!$ and $35\not\mid5!$ - lagrange's theorem), this means that $|\text{Im}(\phi)|=5$. Hence the kernel of this homomorphism has order $35/5=7$ and every kernel of a homomorphism is a normal subgroup.

Maybe this should give you an idea of where to start, assuming you are talking about group actions.